# Setting Focus on a @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, focus

I am having troubles of getting the focus of a textbox to work correctly.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#focus').focus();
    });
</script>
```

--

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ListFields[i].Value, new { id = "focus" })<br />
```

Comment: And what's the actual, resulting, rendered HTML of that textbox? Is the id "focus"?

Comment: Are you doing that in a loop ? You should not give same ID for more than one item

Comment: @J.Steen: Are you sure it can not be set manually? If you override it in an editor template, you can override it. Tested.

Comment: Yes sorry it is being set in a loop on the first iteration. So it is only set once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` is set by `TextBoxFor` (mainly what makes it "for" a model field is having a name/id that matches the property name).

It's better to use a microformat like `new { uifocus = "focus" }` (or just a class, if you prefer).  You can select like:

```
$('input[uifocus=focus]').focus();
```